# Как остановить docker-compose (docker container)?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

Каким образом остановить *docker-compose*, если в нём указана дериктива `restart: always`? Всякий раз при остановке, через некоторое время контейнер опять поднимается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотря что вы имеете ввиду под "остановить" и как. По умолчанию логика такая (из [документации](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/)):

> If you manually stop a container, its restart policy is ignored until
>   the Docker daemon restarts or the container is manually restarted.
>   This is another attempt to prevent a restart loop.

То есть если вы остановите контейнер "руками" то политика рестарта будет проигнорена до тех пор пока вы сами не рестартанете контейнер или не ребутнете докер демона.

Если вы хотите чтобы и рестарт докер-демона не влиял, то используйте restart:unless-stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в каталоге ввести в терминал команду - docker-compose stop

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь в будущем оставлять немного более развернутые ответы. Будет также хорошо, если вы улучшите этот ответ.

Comment: а что нового добавляет ваш ответ к уже существующему (помимо того, что он не совсем «в тему»)?